# MQTT.js (mosqutio broker) - I get the same message several times

Tags: javascript, angular, mqtt

I have two applications. I get the same message several times.

For example:

- app1 -> user_1 writes message: 'I need help' topic: demo
- app2 -> show list of chats
- app2 -> user_2 open chat from list and subscribe to topic:demo and now can talk with user_1

app2 user_2

- I need help
- I need help
- I need help
- I need help
- I need help

It seems that connection is created several times.
It seems that subscribe and publish to different topic also not working. App1:

```
   let client = mqtt.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9001', {
      clientId: "front-client",
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin",
    });
    client.on('connect', (topic) => {
      client.subscribe(this.topic, (err) => {
        if (!err) {}
      });
    });
    this.mqttClient = client;
    //handle incoming messages
    client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
      this.showMessageFromMqtt(message);
    });
  }
  sendMsgByMqtt(message: string) {
    this.mqttClient.publish(this.topic + '/MSG', message, {retain: true});
  }

App2:
  configureMqttChannel() {
    let client = mqtt.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9001', {
      clientId: "front-client-angular",
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin"
    });
    // console.log("connected flag:  " + client.connected);
    client.on('connect', (topic) => {
      // console.log("connected  " + client.connected);
      client.subscribe(this.topic + '/MSG', (err) => {
        if (!err) {
          // console.log('message sent by mqtt')
          // client.publish(this.topic, '', {retain: true})
        }
      });
    });
    this.mqttClient = client;

    //handle incoming messages
    client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
      // console.log("message is " + message);
      // console.log("topic is " + topic);
      this.showMessageFromMqtt(message);
    });
  }

  sendMsgByMqtt(message: string) {
    this.mqttClient.publish(this.topic, message, {retain: true});
  }
```

In browser console:
connected  true
connected  true
connected  true
connected  true
connected  true
connected  true
connected  true
......

Comment: Note: You're going to get your own messages back if you are subscribed to the same topic that you're publishing to.

Comment: It sounds like a loop of some sort, but since your code example has no `client.publish()`, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to publish and subscribe to the same topic then your message must include an identifier that allows you to filter out messages that you've published when they invariably come back to you.

An example of this would be (pseudo code):

```
const MY_IDENTIFIER = generateSomeIdentifierUniqueToThisClient();

publish({
   identifier:MY_IDENTIFIER,
   data: // the actual content of your message
});

handleIncoming = data => {
  // this was a message you sent
  if(data.identifier === MY_IDENTIFIER) return;

  // handle it
}
```

An alternative solution is to publish to say, demo/someUniqueClientIdentifier and subscribe to demo/+

When you receive a message, you can use the topic name to see which client it came from and filter it out that way - a variation on the exact same thing as above.